# FB.logout() does not logout user from Facebook session

Tags: javascript, facebook, logout

Implemented Login with Facebook successfully. Now each time user use this "Login with Facebook", his Facebook session is created in browser(Facebook home page shows this user as logged in). I do not want Facebook session to become active when user uses "Login with Facebook", and I just want Facebook to authenticate this user and send my application his first name, last name and email which I am able to get successfully. Now to invalidate Facebook session, I am calling  FB.logout() but it does not logout user from Facebook session and I can still see user is logged in on Facebook home page.

I had also tried https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=[YourAppURL]&access_token=[ValidAccessToken], but this take user to his home page and does not logout.

How to invalidate Facebook session and logout user out from Facebook using java/javascript.

Comment: Whether this logs the user out of your app only, or your app and Facebook, depends on whether the user logged in to Facebook specifically to log into your app, or whether they had been logged in to Facebook before already.

Comment: They have not logged into Facebook before and had specifically to log into my app using login with Facebook. Its does not log user out of my app also (which I am not expecting).

Comment: It might have logged them out of your app - but if they stay logged in to Facebook, and your app is set up to automatically “log in” recurring users, then they will get logged in again immediately. So for starters, you would have to disable any such auto-login functionality.

Comment: Browser concole logs - FB.logout() called without an access token

Comment: Well then check whether you were still successfully logged in at that point.